# Gitgnore parser in Dart

Tags: dart, parsing, gitignore

I search a dart lib or dart code to do the same thing like js gitignore parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-gitignore?activeTab=code

any idea or example ?

Thank you

Comment: All this really is is a loop over the lines, that keeps only lines that are not empty and don't start with "#"

Comment: no no. i don't want to parse the gitignore file. but filter a list of files applying patterns in gitignore file

Comment: The readme states that since v1 they don't parse anything - they let you parse it. You can just read the correct file and then parse the lines with `glob` package

Answer (score 0):

i find a good example to answer my question in https://github.com/onepub-dev/onepub/blob/1ff7e81d450ebcab984bc9a3f69b224941e20f6d/lib/src/pub/ignore.dart

Comment: Please add code in your solution, as links in the future might not work anymore and this answer will no longer be useful.